# Baby locked phone through android device manager can't unlock

Tags: android-device-manager

I think somehow my baby locked my phone and i can't unlock it I even tried changing the password and that doesn't work. I have an HTC One M8. Any clues how I can get back into my phone? If my baby locked it there's no way of guessing a password that would unlock it

Answer (score 0):

Send a lock command via ADM with a new passcode, if the phone is online it should update in a few minutes and you will get a confirmation it has been locked and updated. If that fails, repeated enter incorrect passcodes, it should eventually give you an option to unlock it with your Google account credentials. Worst case scenario, factory default and set it up new, the worst that would happen is lose everything on your phone and you have to unlock FRP (Factory Reset Protection) with your Google account credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your device is connected to the Internet and that it's connected to your Google account aswell, in order to change your lock screen password you can start your web browser (I recommend using Google Chrome), then head to [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com.br/android/devicemanager) and click the **Lock** button. A pop-up window will ask you to inform the new password and confirm it.

If resetting your screen lock doesn't solve the problem, you'll have to go to [Google My Account](https://myaccount.google.com/security/signinoptions/password) and reset your Google account password. This will cause your device to be disconnected from your Google account. Then reset your device by pressing and holding the **power** and **volume up** buttons simultaneously for about 10 seconds. Your device will reboot the Android system and then you should be able to add your existing Google account again.

If no "add new account" option comes up after the reboot, you'll have to perform a **factory reset**. In order to do it, follow these steps:

1. Switch your device off (hold down the **power** button until your device powers off).
2. Press and hold the **power** and **volume down** buttons.
3. When you see the colorful bootloader menu with three Android mascots on the botton, release the buttons, then press **volume down** to select the option `Factory reset`.
4. Press the **power** button to confirm.

After the factory reset, make sure your device is connected to the Internet so you can add your existing Google account again. If your Android device was configured to perform regular system backups on the cloud, most of your apps and configurations will be restored from the backup.

Afterwards, it's recommended to set up a new screen lock password or drawing pattern, in order to avoid future accidental phone lockings.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guy, it seems like Android Device Manager doesn't push new lock-screen passwords to overwrite the old one anymore. You'll have to do a Factory Data reset, or the "Erase" button on the ADM. I'm so sorry for your loss.